# FreeTDS - Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist

Tags: centos, freetds, unixodbc

CENTOS 6.5 x86_64
WHM 11.42.1
unixODBC 2.2.14

### freetds v0.91

I'm trying to connect to remote MSSQL server without success - also tried connecting with different tds versions (4.2, 7.0, 7.1, 8.0) but all give the same result.

Using the same servername, port, username and password, I'm able to connect via my desktop using Win7 and SQL Server Management Studio.

Telnet also fails.

Details follow. Please let me know if you need any more. All help/advice appreciated.

========

## tsql -C

```
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /etc
     MS db-lib source compatibility: yes
        Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 4.2
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: yes
```

========

## tsql -H testDSN -pXXXX -U 'testuser' -P 'testpass'

```
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF8"
20Error 20009 (severity 9):
        Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
        OS error 110, "Connection timed out"
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

=======

## isql -v testDSN 'testuser' 'testpass'

```
[S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
[08S01][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

========
osql -S testDSN -U 'testuser' -P 'testpass'
...

```
Configuration looks OK.  Connection details:

                   DSN: testDSN
              odbc.ini: /etc/odbc.ini
                Driver: /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so
       Server hostname: winsrv106.pleskdns.co.uk
               Address: x.x.x.x

Attempting connection as testuser ...
+ isql testDSN testuser 'testpass' -v
[S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
[08S01][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
net.c:205:FAILED Connecting to x.x.x.x port XXXX (TDS version 7.1)
```

========

## more freetds.log

```
log.c:196:Starting log file for FreeTDS 0.91
        on 2014-04-10 15:33:03 with debug flags 0x4fff.
iconv.c:330:tds_iconv_open(0x7233e0, UTF8)
iconv.c:187:local name for ISO-8859-1 is ISO-8859-1
iconv.c:187:local name for UTF-8 is UTF-8
iconv.c:187:local name for UCS-2LE is UCS-2LE
iconv.c:187:local name for UCS-2BE is UCS-2BE
iconv.c:349:setting up conversions for client charset "UTF8"
iconv.c:351:preparing iconv for "UTF8" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion
iconv.c:391:preparing iconv for "ISO-8859-1" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion
iconv.c:394:tds_iconv_open: done
net.c:205:Connecting to x.x.x.x port XXXX (TDS version 7.1)
net.c:270:tds_open_socket: connect(2) returned "Operation now in progress"
net.c:306:getsockopt(2) reported: Connection timed out
net.c:316:tds_open_socket() failed
util.c:331:tdserror(0x723140, 0x7233e0, 20009, 110)
util.c:361:tdserror: client library returned TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
util.c:384:tdserror: returning TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
mem.c:615:tds_free_all_results()
```

========

## telnet x.x.x.x

```
Trying x.x.x.x... 
telnet: connect to address x.x.x.x: 
Connection timed out
```

Comment: Does anyone know what "Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist" means?

Comment: As I'm connecting via SQL Server Management Studio, the remote server credentials must be ok... and osql states "Configuration looks OK" on the local server. The only clue is in freetds.log which states "tds_open_socket() failed". Does anyone know what can be causing this?

Comment: Just found this:

"Unable to open socket" is TDSECONN produced by src/tds/net.c::tds_open_socket(). It's the result of a failure of inet_addr(3) or (more likely) socket(3).  While it's true you can't connect, more precisely you're prevented *locally* from attempting to connect.  To connect you need a  local resource -- a socket -- and you're unable to create one.

I expect the log to show "socket creation error" and the OS's error message.  I wouldn't be surprised if EACCES is the problem.  (In which case telnet(1) will also fail.)

http://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/freetds/2009q3/025094.html

Comment: SOLVED after required port on local server was opened inbound and outbound

Comment: Hi, we have the same error. Can you tell me how you specifically solved this? I spent almost 2 days of this error. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and solved it by using a custom port: 
port = XXXXX
in freetds.conf
This port should be configured in SQL Server Configuration Mgnt

SQL Server Network Configuration -> TCP/IP (enabled) -> IP Addresses -> IPAll -> TCP Dynamic Ports

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx

Comment: I also had to add a `tds version = 8.0` line to my freetds.conf

Answer (score 2):

I run MS Windows in VirtualBox.

So for me to access MS SQLServer from my mac host I must:

- Add Port Forwarding entry in VirtualBox > Devices > Network > Network
  Settings > Advanced
- Open Port 1444 in MS Control Panel > Windows Firewall > Advanced
  Settings > Inbound Rules
- Start SQL Server Browser in SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL
  Server Services
- Enable TCP in SQL Server Configuration Manager > Protocols
- Set TCP Port to 1444 for TCPAll in SQL Server Configuration Manager > Protocols > TCP/IP > Properties...

[image: Set TCP Port to 1444]

Note that MS SQL Server is configured to listen on port 1444.

Comment: Thank you very much . your solution worked for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this error when using Pymssql for the first time. I had to turn on TCP/IP as the one of the network protocols for my local install of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Similar resolution for me on a Cygwin 64 install interfacing FreeTDS to a SQL Server 2008 database on a local machine.  Had to enable the TCP/IP protocol for the MSSQLServer Service and restart the service to resolve.

freetds.log trace activation led me to the solution (log sample follows):

```
11:16:13.960012 10688 (log.c:167):Starting log file for FreeTDS 0.95.69
    on 2015-11-26 11:16:13 with debug flags 0xffff.<br>
11:16:13.960012 10688 (iconv.c:328):tds_iconv_open(0x60004b500, UTF-8)<br>
11:16:13.960012 10688 (iconv.c:187):local name for ISO-8859-1 is ISO-8859-1<br>
11:16:13.960012 10688 (iconv.c:187):local name for UTF-8 is UTF-8<br>
11:16:13.960012 10688 (iconv.c:187):local name for UCS-2LE is UCS-2LE<br>
11:16:13.960012 10688 (iconv.c:187):local name for UCS-2BE is UCS-2BE<br>
11:16:13.960012 10688 (iconv.c:346):setting up conversions for client charset "UTF-8"<br>
11:16:13.960012 10688 (iconv.c:348):preparing iconv for "UTF-8" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion<br>
11:16:13.960012 10688 (iconv.c:395):preparing iconv for "ISO-8859-1" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion<br>
11:16:13.960012 10688 (iconv.c:400):tds_iconv_open: done<br>
11:16:13.960012 10688 (net.c:202):Connecting to ?.?.?.? port 1433 (TDS version 7.3)<br><br>
11:16:13.963012 10688 (net.c:274):tds_open_socket: connect(2) returned "Operation now in progress"<br>
11:16:14.963069 10688 (net.c:309):getsockopt(2) reported: Connection refused<br>
11:16:14.963069 10688 (net.c:319):tds_open_socket() failed<br>
11:16:14.963069 10688 (util.c:322):tdserror(0x600049ad0, 0x60004b500, 20009, 111)<br>
11:16:14.963069 10688 (odbc.c:2343):msgno 20009 20003<br>
11:16:14.963069 10688 (util.c:352):tdserror: client library returned TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)<br>
11:16:14.963069 10688 (util.c:375):tdserror: returning TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)<br>
11:16:14.963069 10688 (mem.c:648):tds_free_all_results()<br>
11:16:14.964069 10688 (error.c:414):odbc_errs_add: "Unable to connect to data source"<br>
11:16:14.964069 10688 (error_export.h:23):SQLError(0x0, 0x600049b70, 0x0, 0x22ba50, 0x22ba4c, 0x22c540, 513, 0x22ba46)<br>
11:16:14.964069 10688 (error.c:565):SQLGetDiagRec: "[FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist"<br>
11:16:14.964069 10688 (error_export.h:23):SQLError(0x0, 0x600049b70, 0x0, 0x22ba50, 0x22ba4c, 0x22c540, 513, 0x22ba46)<br>
11:16:14.964069 10688 (error.c:565):SQLGetDiagRec: "[FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source"<br>
```